# Use of the word "hypothesis"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

So I was correcting an essay of my friend, and when I was reading the conclusion I read this:

> This essay discussed how e-rating teachers by learners can help trainers to ameliorate their teaching strategies and can also provide inaccurate results. In my opinion, grading mentors online by students is a good hypothesis.

I was telling her that I believe that *hypothesis* is not a good use of the word in this context. For me "form of evaluation, "approach", or even "idea" are better words to use here. She argued that she was corrected by an English tutor and he didn't mention anything about the word "hypothesis" . I still think it is not accurate or well used. Any lights on this?

Answer (score 2):

A [hypothesis](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypothesis) is a proposed explanation for some phenomenon. And, in science, one that needs to be tested in order to become a theory.

So I agree, this does not seem to be an appropriate use of the word. Your suggestions seem better.